# nginx config to force www but allow m causes a 503

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

We're trying to use the following rules to force www and allow m subdomains:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com;
       set $test 0;
       if ($host !~* ^www\.){
                set $test 1;
        }

        if ($host ~* ^m\.){
                set $test 2;
        }

        if ( $test = 1 ) {
                return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/tmp.error.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/home/;
        index index.html index.php;
    }
}
```

What we're seeing is that it works at first, for a few minutes, and then it suddenly stops working. As soon as we comment out the rules in the first section, it works perfectly again. Any ideas?

Comment: See some of the [problems with if here](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#Examples).

Comment: But this isn't inside location, as that example shows

Comment: The link isn't about where the `if` statement is, it's about the assumptions for `if` statements being misleading sometimes.

Comment: Either way, I don't think this particular case is a misuse of the if statement, do you?